# Is it possible to change the C++ Executables output folder on build.gradle?

Tags: c++, gradle

I have a C++ project using gradle. Could I change its output target folder?  Which part of build.gradle should I update?

Comment: Well, to answer you which part of `build.gradle` you need to update, you should post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Sunny, what exactly do you want to configure? The directory where the object files are generated into? Then what you are after is probably `cppCompile.objectFileDirectory.set file('whatever')` or similar.